# Objects and Strings equality and memory digrams

Tags: java, string, object, equality

I have having a bit of trouble understanding the difference between these two:

Suppose we have:

```
 String x = "Test";
 String y = x;
 y = "Not Test"; //x is not modified here
```

The memory diagram for these two steps is the following:

1. x-> "Test"
2. x-> "Test" <-y
3. x-> "Test" y-> "Not Test"

But, consider class A with field 'int var':

```
A a = new A();
A b = a;
b.var = 5;
```

Here, if we modify b.var, a.var also changes to 5. Why is this different from the above case with strings?

Additionally, I would appreciate it if someone wouldn't mind explaining these memory diagrams for strings and objects. Would the result be different if a and b were objects of different classes set equal? Thanks.

Comment: String  immutable in Java. So when you do 'y = "Not Test"', then new String created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between

```
b.var = 5;
```

and

```
b = new A();
```

The second statement is similar to what you do in your first snippet, since `y = "Not Test";` makes `y` refer to a new instance.

The first statement updates the state of the instance referred by both `a` and `b`, so both are affected.

Here's a diagram that shows your second snippet :

```
a -> object of class A <- b
     containing an int
     variable `var`
        var <- 5
```

Both `a.var` and `b.var` contain 5, since they are the same variable.

Answer (score 2):

Because `String` is [Immutable class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html), *state* of which class can not be changed. While `A` is mutable because you changed it's state by changing value of variable. Secondly, both `a` and `b` are referencing to the same memory location and changing state of one will get reflected in second one but that's not the case in case of `String` if `String` `a` and `b` is `Test` changing `a` to `Test1` will not change the `Test` to `Test1` but it will create new `String` `Test1` and assign it to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case they are both pointing at the same place in the memory.

```
A a = new A();     a-->[MEMORY SPOT NR1]
A b = a;           a-->[MEMORY SPOT NR1] AND b-->[MEMORY SPOT NR1]
b.var = 5;         a-->[MEMORY SPOT NR1] AND b-->[MEMORY SPOT NR1] 
                   and the value in var in [MEMORY SPOT NR1] is 5, 
                   so both a.var and b.var take the value 5
```